# Error: Error: This socket has been ended by the other party [object Undefined]

Tags: node.js, sockets

So i am building this MMORPG which is basicaly just a training ground for me and it's nothing really big and i dont aim to sell it or make any money of it, it's just for fun and for experiments.

There is an error which didn't bother me before but now it's getting pretty out of hand and i don't know what is causing this to happen error.

So the error i am getting isn't effecting server but it's keep crashing other clients in the room, for example if there is 3 players in the room and one decides to go to other room which send packet to all clients that are online that says that player moved to another room but if the player goes back to the previous room or send packet from the room he is currently in it will crash random clients game, the game just freezes and nothing can be done you can only force process to end in the task manager.
I've tried debugging in the client side and when the game crashes i see that it crashes becouse server is spamming packets and the client can't handle it.

the errors i am getting are :
`Error: Error: This socket has been ended by the other party [object Undefined]`
`Error: Error: This socket is closed [object Undefined]`

What is causing these errors? Does anyone have any idea how to maybe fix it?

Comment: I wish people who write error messages wouldn't confuse sockets with connections. What it really means is that the *connection* has been ended by the peer. Only the local application has access to the local socket, and only it can clode it.